# Unable to configure accounts-facebook in Meteor application

Tags: facebook, meteor, meteor-accounts

I've added the packages accounts-base, accounts-ui and accounts-facebook to my meteor app. I understand that by adding {{> loginButtons}} to my template the configure/login buttons will popup on my template. However, with only the accounts-facebook as login package I get the message: "No login services configured"
When adding accounts-github and accounts-google the buttons do show up and everything seems to work normally. So it's seems related to the Facebook package itself, but I've run out of ideas how to solve this problem. Anyone else having an idea?

Comment: Are you sure that `accounts-facebook` shows up when typing `meteor list` ? Also, which version of Meteor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out my Ghostery and ABP where blocking social media plugins. Not really smart of me to switch those off when developing for these networks... Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing `accounts-facebook`. Double check you have it in your project:

```
meteor add accounts-facebook
```

Also, just ensure that you dont have a custom `accounts-facebook` package in the package folder of your meteor app which may be overriding the meteor system one.

Comment: I just added some other account options. Github, Google and Weibo are working without problems, but Twitter does have the same problem.
Also I don't seem to have a package folder in my app folder. I'm using Meteor version 0.9.3.1. My output of meteor list:
accounts-base          1.1.1
accounts-facebook      1.0.1 
accounts-twitter       1.0.1
accounts-ui            1.1.1
facebook               1.1.0
ian:bootstrap-3        1.0.3
meteor-platform        1.1.1
service-configuration  1.0.1
twitter                1.1.0